# $\frac{\cos x_1}{\cos x_2}=1-\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2 -x_2^2)+ \vert\vert x\vert\vert^2\epsilon(x),$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Im trying to prove this equality$$\frac{\cos x_1}{\cos x_2}=1-\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2 -x_2^2)+ \vert\vert x\vert\vert^2\epsilon(x),$$

where $\epsilon(x)\to0$ as $x\to (0,0)$. I tried reducing $1-\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2 -x_2^2)$, and dividing with the square of the norm so we could prove the limit of the resulting expression. The problem is that $\vert\vert x \vert\vert^2$ will be in the denominator.

I think the Taylor series for $\cos x$ might be useful here, but simply substituting them is not enough. I'm just looking for a hint, not a detailed solution.

Comment: If you assume that $x_1,x_2$ are in the vicinity of $0$, which is necessary for your formula being meaningful, it looks me natural to consider $(1-x_1^2/2+\|x_1\|^2 \epsilon_1(x_1))/(1-x_2^2/2+\|x_2\|^2 \epsilon_2(x_2))=...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that by $\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+o(x^2)$

$$\frac{\cos x_1}{\cos x_2}=\frac{1-\frac12x_1^2+o(\|x\|^3)}{1-\frac12 x_2^2+o(\|x\|^3)}=\left(1-\frac12x_1^2+o(\|x\|^3)\right)\left(1+\frac12 x_2^2+o(\|x\|^3)\right)=$$

$$=1-\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2 -x_2^2)+o(\|x\|^3)$$

Comment: Are you sure the 9 terms of that product really cancel into that 3 term sum?

Comment: @variations We have that $x_1^2 o(\|x\|^3)=o(\|x\|^3)$ and of course $o(\|x\|^3)\cdot o(\|x\|^3)=o(\|x\|^3)$, therefore yes no other terms survive.